Vector Space Construction from Common Polynomial Roots
Given two polynomials $p_1, p_2 \in \mathbb{K}[x]$, is there a canonical construction of a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{K}$ such that $\dim(V)$ equals the number of roots (counted with multiplicity) that $p_1$ and $p_2$ share in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{K}$?
Edit: Having though about it, perhaps the following is a better way to ask this question:
is there an alternative way of characterising $\mathbb{K}[x]/(g)$ in terms of $p_1$ and $p_2$, when $g = \text{gcd}(p_1,p_2)$ ?

I don't know how "canonical" this is, but the $\ker$ of the (transposed) Sylvester matrix has dimension equal to the degree of the gcd, so you may take that.

But isn’t $k[x]/(g)$ already really canonical?

Also you could use companion matrices to build (very similar and very isomorphic) algebras
